# Can I just share my URL and have the app wirelessely downloaded to the device through In House Distribution?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution, enterprise-distribution

We just have a small problem and we are hoping to fix it.

We are sick and tired of sharing our app through AdHoc Distribution and adding every device's UDID that can download our app wirelessely through a link. (Yes, we want users to privately download our app through our link).

Now, we have been striving to do it without the hassle of adding UDID of every device. We looked around and found that if we have bought Enterprise Developer Account, **In House Distribution** would allow us to do everything that AdHoc Distribution does but without the hassle of adding every device's UDID that downloads the app.

So, I just wanted to confirm that can I allow user to wirelessely download the app to his/her device without adding the device's UDID through In House Distribution in Enterprise Account?

Your comment would save many years of life.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enterprise account can do that but you don't just buy one. Apple requires a pile of documentation to evidence your suitability for the programme.

Instead, you should just have your testers install iOS 8 and use the new version of TestFlight that's integrated into iTunes.

In the new scheme, you'd get the Apple account email addresses of everyone who wanted to be a tester. You'd add them as test users to your iTunes Connect account (so, they'd need not to be members of any other iTunes Connect account).

You submit a build to iTunes Connect, signed the usual distribution way.

Instead of ticking it for Apple to review, you'd tick in up to 25 of your test users to test. They can then download it through the TestFlight app from the App Store, on as many devices as they own.

You don't collect or manage UDIDs and there's no annual limit on test users. All you need is their email addresses.

Apple [has a splash page with further information](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/) to explain the new mechanism to developers.

Answer (score 1):

[**Yes.**](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) You can distribute an enterprise-signed app without collecting UDIDs. I will add, however, that it is intended for distribution to employees. Make sure you aren't violating the terms of service of your enterprise account.